# Calculating which pay period a date falls into in google script

Tags: javascript, forms, google-apps-script

I have a  Google form that asks users to enter PTO requests. I am writing a script that calculates which pay period the PTO starts in. I have tried to copy answers to similar questions on other threads but I my code is not working. I have the following snippets:

```
var FIRST_PAY_PERIOD = new Date("5/01/2016"); //Sunday of First pay period
var MILLISECONDS_IN_DAY = 86400000;

function SheetHandler(sheet) {
    var _sheet = sheet;
    var _data = getRowsData(_sheet);

    var _markPending = function(d) {

    d.state = PENDING_STATE;
    d.identifier = Utils.generateUUID();

    var startOfLeave = Date(d.leaveStartDate);

    var payPeriod = FIRST_PAY_PERIOD + (Math.floor(((startOfLeave - FIRST_PAY_PERIOD) / MILLISECONDS_IN_DAY)/14) * 14);

    Logger.log("First Pay Period " +FIRST_PAY_PERIOD);
    Logger.log("Start of Leave " +startOfLeave);
    Logger.log ("Delta " +(startOfLeave - FIRST_PAY_PERIOD));
    Logger.log("Pay Period " +payPeriod);

    d.payPeriod = payPeriod;
```

The logger output is as follows:

[16-05-11 10:28:10:914 PDT] First Pay Period Sun May 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)

[16-05-11 10:28:10:915 PDT] Start of Leave Wed May 11 2016 10:28:10 GMT-0700 (PDT)

[16-05-11 10:28:10:916 PDT] Delta NaN

[16-05-11 10:28:10:917 PDT] Pay Period Sun May 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)NaN

Code question - why am I getting "NaN" as the delta between the 2 dates? 
Formating question - how do I write out the calculated pay period as just "05/15/2016"?

Comment: are you sure the `NaN` is still there after you wrapped `(startOfLeave - FIRST_PAY_PERIOD)` in parens? That would be the error if you had not wrapped that subtraction in parens.

Comment: What are the data types of the variables `FIRST_PAY_PERIOD` and `startOfLeave`?  `Logger.log("typeof startOfLeave: " + typeof startOfLeave);`  Run the code, then in the VIEW menu, choose LOGS.

Comment: Yes, the output is as shown with the code as shown. I see the NaN both in the logger output and when it's written back to the spreadsheet

Comment: @sandy-good They are 2 different types: 
[16-05-11 11:23:49:366 PDT] typeof startOfLeave: string
[16-05-11 11:23:49:367 PDT] typeof FIRST_PAY_PERIOD: object

Is that the problem? How do I change the type of whichever one is in error?

Comment: I removed the "new" from 
    var FIRST_PAY_PERIOD = new Date("5/01/2016"); //Sunday of First pay period
and now both are showing up as type string. However the "NaN" is still there:
[16-05-11 11:42:32:501 PDT] typeof startOfLeave: string
[16-05-11 11:42:32:502 PDT] typeof FIRST_PAY_PERIOD: string
[16-05-11 11:42:32:502 PDT] First Pay Period Wed May 11 2016 11:42:31 GMT-0700 (PDT)
[16-05-11 11:42:32:503 PDT] Start of Leave Wed May 11 2016 11:42:32 GMT-0700 (PDT)
[16-05-11 11:42:32:503 PDT] Delta NaN
[16-05-11 11:42:32:504 PDT] Pay Period Wed May 11 2016 11:42:31 GMT-0700 (PDT)NaN

Comment: In order to get the difference between `startOfLeave - FIRST_PAY_PERIOD` the data types of both should both be a number.  One way to do math on dates is to convert the date object to milliseconds.   In JavaScript you can use the `getTime()` method on a date object to return the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new to your original code for startOfLeave

```
var startOfLeave = new Date(d.leaveStartDate);
```

Date() by itself ignores arguments and just gives you a string of the current date, time and timezone. It is trying to do math on that string that is generating all of the NaN's.

Comment: Thank you. That fixed the first part of the problem. But now I realize that
    (Math.floor(((startOfLeave - FIRST_PAY_PERIOD) / MILLISECONDS_IN_DAY)/14) * 14)
returns the integer number of days to add to FIRST_PAY_PERIOD. How do I convert that number to a format so that it can be correctly added to FIRST_PAY_PERIOD to give the correct payroll period?

Comment: i increment date objects by

new Date(old_date.valueOf() + delta_in_milliseconds)

Comment: Doing that would basically undo all of the math you did and give you something very close to startOfLeave.

if the answer you want is 3 when the leave starts in the third pay period delete the *14 from your math. May still be off by one depending on what exactly you want and how you number your pay periods.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help from the various posters. I took everyone's input and came up with the following which works:

```
var FIRST_PAY_PERIOD = new Date("5/01/2016"); //Sunday of First pay period

var startOfLeave = new Date(d.leaveStartDate);

var firstPayPeriodSecs = FIRST_PAY_PERIOD.getTime();

var ptoDurationSecs = (Math.floor(((startOfLeave - FIRST_PAY_PERIOD) / MILLISECONDS_IN_DAY)/14) * 14 * MILLISECONDS_IN_DAY);

var payPeriod = new Date(firstPayPeriodSecs + ptoDurationSecs);
```